# Converting a list of dates to a proper date type format in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dates:

```
dates = ["Jan2016","Feb2016","Mar2016"]
```

I want to convert these dates to a *datetime format* i.e Jan2016 = 201601

My first thought was to create a dict of months and their associated numbers and then map that over the list.

```
months = {"Jan":1,"Feb":2,"Mar":3}
```

Here is my current code:

```
dates = ["Jan2016","Feb2016","Mar2016"]
dic   = {"Jan":1, "Feb":2,"Mar":3}

month = []
year  = []

for date in dates:
    month.append(date[:3])
    year.append(date[3:])


month = [dic[n] if n in dic else n for n in month]

d = dict(zip(month,year))

print(d)
```

The output of this code is a dict like so:

```
{1: '2016', 2: '2016', 3: '2016'}
```

What is the most pythonic solution to this problem?

Comment: A datetime implies that there is a day and a time too. You only have a month and year.

Comment: Why a dictionary? What should happen with `['Jan2015', 'Jan2016']`?

Comment: This is true. For this example the day and time is inconsequential as long as the months are formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As @Martijin commented, you can not have a datetime as `201601`, but if you want a string instead, you can use `strptime` and `strftime` from datetime module to convert:

```
dates = ["Jan2016","Feb2016","Mar2016"]

from datetime import datetime

[datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(d, "%b%Y"), "%Y%m") for d in dates]

# ['201601', '201602', '201603']
```

---

In case you are not familiar with *conversion specification*, `%b` stands for month abbreviation names, `%Y` Year with century, `%m` Month as decimal number(0-12)

Comment: You should remove `import datetime` since it is unused.

Answer (score 1):

hello you can try with  a map()

```
months = {"Jan":"01", "Feb":"02", "Mar":"03"}
dates = ["Jan2016","Feb2016","Mar2016"]
list = map(lambda x :x[3:] + months[x[:3]], dates)
```

ouput:

> ['201601', '201602', '201603']

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('Jan2016', '%b%Y')
```

For your list, you can combine the above with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> res = [datetime.strptime(d, '%b%Y') for d in dates]
>>> [datetime.strftime(d, "%Y%m") for d in res]
['201601', '201602', '201603']
```

**Note:** Since the day is missing in your dates list, 1 would be used for day (for `res` items).